# Automation scripts are getting failed in Headless executions

Tags: selenium, webdriver, headless

My automation suites are well executed in head mode. Recently I tried Docker and learned that I need to run suites in headless executions. So I tried to run my suites in Chrome with headless option and weirdly some locators are not detected by Selenium webdriver java. I rigorously tried in all possible ways i.e waits, in all google suggested ways but no luck below is the error I am also getting with headless

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by:

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: The error clearly states that the code failed waiting for the presence of element. You need to share your code in order of this to debug